# How can I generate attributes with obj2xml for ruby classes generated from xsd2ruby?

Tags: ruby, xml, xsd, soap4r

I've used the utility xsd2ruby utility provided with soap4r to generate the required classes from an XSD schema definition file. This works well, however when I try to generate an xml file using XSD::Mapping.obj2xml the attributes do not get created as I expect (or would like). I would like the following:

```
  <obj attr1=value1 attr2=value2>
    <element1>value</element1>
  </obj>
```

but this is what gets generated:

```
 <obj>
    <__xmlattr>
      <item>
        <key>
          <name>attr1</name>
          <namespace></namespace>
          <source></source>
        </key>
        <value>value1</value>
      </item>
      <item>
        <key>
          <name>attr2</name>
          <namespace></namespace>
          <source></source>
        </key>
        <value>value2</value>
      </item>
    </__xmlattr>
    <element1>value</element1>
  </obj>
```

How can I generate the XML output without the xmlattr?

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember `XSD::Mapping.obj2xml` XML will use an instance's instance variables as element names and their values as child elements. That's all. With the instance variable `@__xmlattr` getting special processing, as you can see.

To get around these limitations I wrote [jaxb2ruby](https://github.com/sshaw/jaxb2ruby). It generates classes based on an ERB template. You can use one of the builtin templates ([ROXML](https://github.com/Empact/roxml), [HappyMapper](https://github.com/jnunemaker/happymapper), or plain ruby class) or write your own.

It's not perfect but has worked out well for me in several instances.

You may also want to checkout [ROAR](https://github.com/apotonick/roar).